# Error Latex con un comando que ya está definido

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

me está saliendo un error en rmarkdown al hacer knit para generar un pdf. El error es el siguiente:

```
! LaTeX Error:  Command  \chead already defined.
                Or name  \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

El inicio del código que he usado es el siguiente:

```
---
title: Auditoría del sistema de iluminación
author: David Sánchez
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d/%m/%Y')`"
documentclass: article
principal: true
forprint: false 
fontsize: 12pt 
toc: true
lang: es


geometry: margin = 2.5cm 
titlepage: true
titlepage-rule-color: "377DA6"
titlepage-background: "/Portada.pdf"
urlcolor: blue


output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    fig_caption: yes
    template: eisvogel

header-includes:
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm}
  \addtolength{\footskip}{-1.25cm}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
  \usepackage{pdflscape}
  \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
  \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}


---
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\textit{\leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
```

Creo que el problema está en el paquete fancyhdr, por lo que he leido en internet, pero no consigo solucionarlo. Y es raro porque exáctamente este código me funciona en el ordenador de sobremesa (windows 10), pero me falla en el portátil (windows 11).

Podría alguien echarme una mano para solucionarlo y así poder trabajar con el portátil?.

Tengo que añadir que soy un usuario muy principiante de LaTeX y que he probado con TinyTex y Miktex y he tenido el mismo problema con ambos, aunque en realidad no entiendo la diferencia entre ambos.

Pongo aquí un enlace al documento .tex (espero que funcione):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XBGGGaeN9NY30xE1RojE-q26xglDK2QF/view?usp=share_link

Muchas gracias

Comment: No puedo reproducir el error, me corre perfecto. Quizás utilizar `\clearpage` como primera línea después del YAML limpie todo lo que viene desde titlepage. O podrías crear dos plantillas en .tex, una para el preámbulo y otra para la portada

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he probado y no funciona. La verdad es que es un error muy extraño, solo me falla en el portátil, en otros ordenadores corre perfecto. Quizás sea algo del Windows 11

Comment: Usas la instalación desktop de latex o estás utilizando [tinytex](https://yihui.org/tinytex/)? Los R Markdown desde mi Mac han estado fallando últimamente con mi instalación desktop, así que descargué tinytex y problema resuelto

Comment: ¿puedes subir a algún sitio el .tex completo que se genera como paso intermedio y pegar un enlace desde el que se pueda descargar? Vale un ejemplo mínimo en el que aparezca el mismo problema. En el .tex intermedio se pueden ver todos los paquetes que se incluyen para descubrir cuál es el que está intentando redefinir el comando \chead.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el código automáticamente generado por knitr esté intentando definir el comando `\chead` y que alguno de los paquetes que has incluido en tu preámbulo ya haya definido ese comando. También es posible que ese comportamiento dependa de la versión concreta de knitr y que por eso el problema aparezca en una máquina, pero no en otra.

Dar con la solución "buena" es complicado, pues en caso de que efectivamente el comando `\chead` se esté definiendo dos veces ¿cuál será la buena, es decir, la que interesa preservar? Si queremos preservar la versión de `\chead` definida en el paquete externo, entonces habría que evitar que knitr introduzca la suya, lo cual en general será complicado sin modificar el propio código de knitr.

Pero si lo que se quiere es ignorar el `\chead` definido en el paquete externo y reemplazarlo por el que knit añade, esto es más sencillo. Basta que añadas a tu preámbulo el comando:

```latex
\let\chead\undefined
```

Supongo que esto puedes hacerlo en la parte de `header-includes`, al final de la misma. Con esto, si cualquiera de los paquetes incluidos había definido un comando `\chead`, éste se "borrará" (marcará como `\undefined`) por lo que knitr podrá volver a definirlo sin problemas.

Naturalmente cabe esperar efectos secundarios no previstos si la versión "buena" era justamente la que el comando anterior ha "borrado".

### Actualización

A la vista del archivo tex que has enlazado en la pregunta, parece que el problema proviene de que la clase principal utilizada por ese documento es `scrartcl` de la colección de estilos KOMA-script, y además incluyes el paquete `fancyhdr`. Ambos (la clase principal y este paquete) intentan definir el comando `\chead`, cada uno su propia versión.

Prueba a quitar el paquete fancyhdr de tu preámbulo.